# How can I limit the user input to only integers in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a multiple choice survey that allows the user to pick from options 1-x. How can I make it so that if the user enters any characters besides numbers, return something like "That's an invalid answer"

```
def Survey():
    print('1) Blue')
    print('2) Red')
    print('3) Yellow')
    question = int(input('Out of these options\(1,2,3), which is your favourite?'))
    if question == 1:
        print('Nice!')
    elif question == 2:
        print('Cool')
    elif question == 3:
        print('Awesome!')
    else:
        print('That\'s not an option!')
```

Comment: Creae a helper function which tries to convert an input string  by  int(input_string) to int and on exception of value errror , again take input.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your code would become:

```
def Survey():

    print('1) Blue')
    print('2) Red')
    print('3) Yellow')

    while True:
        try:
            question = int(input('Out of these options\(1,2,3), which is your favourite?'))
            break
        except:
            print("That's not a valid option!")

    if question == 1:
        print('Nice!')
    elif question == 2:
        print('Cool')
    elif question == 3:
        print('Awesome!')
    else:
        print('That\'s not an option!')
```

The way this works is it makes a loop that will loop infinitely until only numbers are put in. So say I put '1', it would break the loop. But if I put 'Fooey!' the error that WOULD have been raised gets caught by the `except` statement, and it loops as it hasn't been broken.

Answer (score 7):

The best way would be to use a helper function which can accept a variable type along with the message to take input.

```
def _input(message, input_type=str):
    while True:
      try:
        return input_type (input(message))
    except:pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _input("Only accepting integer : ", int)
    _input("Only accepting float : ", float)
    _input("Accepting anything as string : ")
```

So when you want an integer , you can pass it that i only want integer, just in case you can accept floating number you pass the float as a parameter. It will make your code really slim so if you have to take input 10 times , you don't want to write try catch blocks ten times.

Answer (score 4):

```
def func():
    choice = "Wrong"
    
    while choice.isdigit()==False :
        choice = input("Enter a number: ")
        
        if choice.isdigit()==False:
            print("Wrongly entered: ")
        else:
            return int(choice)
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution amongst others : use the `type` function or `isinstance` function to check if you have an ̀`int` or a `float` or some other type

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>

>>> type(1.5)
<type 'float'>

>>> isinstance(1.5, int)
False

>>> isinstance(1.5, (int, float))
True
```

Comment: It does not answer the question specifically. He wants to convert entered str type into int.

Comment: @AhsanRoy You are right. I'm not sure why I answered that 5 years ago ! I think I answered to this specific part: "How can I make it so that if the user enters **any characters besides numbers**, return ..."

Answer (score 1):

I would catch first the `ValueError` (not integer) exception and check if the answer is acceptable (within 1, 2, 3) or raise another `ValueError` exception

```
def survey():
    print('1) Blue')
    print('2) Red')
    print('3) Yellow')

    ans = 0
    while not ans:
        try:
            ans = int(input('Out of these options\(1, 2, 3), which is your favourite?'))
            if ans not in (1, 2, 3):
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            ans = 0
            print("That's not an option!")

    if ans == 1:
        print('Nice!')
    elif ans == 2:
        print('Cool')
    elif ans == 3:
        print('Awesome!')
    return None
```

Comment: Can be made lot cleaner with a helper function

Answer (score 0):

I made a module for cases like this called [restricted_input](https://pypi.org/project/restricted-input/) which checks the input in real time. Here, since you only need inputs from 1-3, this would do

```py
from restricted_input import r_input
num = int(r_input("Out of these options\(1,2,3), which is your favourite? ", input_type="nothing", allow="123", maxlength=1))
```

It uses msvcrt.getch/termios to get non-blocking input, so it checks it in real time and allows only the specified characters.
Note: This will not work in IDLEs like Spyder, Jupyter etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
# force user to input a number between 0 - 4 (1,2,3)
def input_int():
    num = ""
    i = 0
    while type(num) is not int:
        # user have 3 chance to try:
        if i > 2:
            print("try later")
            exit(1)
        i += 1
        # input int
        try:
            num = int(input("{} form {} try! please insert int num: ".format(i, 3)))
            # checking number for being upper than zero and lower than 3 (1, 2, 3)
            if 0 > num or num > 3:
                num = ""
                print("That's an invalid answer")
                continue
        # if the input is not a int, user have to input another value
        except ValueError:
            print("That's an invalid answer")
            continue
    # if input for num was valid, return num
    return num
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from msvcrt import getch

def survey():
    comment = ['Nice!', 'Cool', 'Awesome!']

    while True:        
        print('\n1) Blue', '2) Red', '3) Yellow', sep='\n', end='')
        print('\nOut of these options\(1,2,3), which is your favourite? ', end='')

        try:
            answer = getch().decode()   # input of 1 character
        except UnicodeDecodeError:      # error from del, home, pg up, etc., keys
            continue

        if answer in '123':    
            print(answer, end=' ')  # print the entered char 
            print(comment[int(answer)-1])
            break             
        else:
            print('\nThat\'s not an option! Please, try again...')

survey()
```

Running on Windows with `msvcrt` standard lib.
If you want to allow a escape way without answering by pressing [ENTER], insert next to the if clause:

```
elif answer == '\r': break
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a module named PyInputPlus.

Installation:

```
pip install PyInputPlus
```

You can use this as

```
def Survey():
    print('1) Blue')
    print('2) Red')
    print('3) Yellow')
    question = int(input('Out of these options\(1,2,3), which is your favourite?'))
    if question == 1:
        print('Nice!')
    elif question == 2:
        print('Cool')
    elif question == 3:
        print('Awesome!')
    else:
        print('That\'s not an option!')
```