# Not allowing users to put a string in the input

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a code for cows and bulls game and am overall happy with my code. Although I was hoping that I could prevent the users from putting a string and breaking the code. I tried using try and except statement in the ask_user but is causing an error in validate number as I am using list.

```
import random

print(""" You have to guess the 4 digit number
The number does not contain 0 in it although you can use 0 to guess the number.
The numbers are not repeated/
All the best.
Type 'exit' to exit the game.
""")
def generate_number():
    global number
    number = int(''.join(random.sample("123456789", 4)))
    return(int(number))

generate_number()
print(number)
def ask_user():
    return input("Enter a number to guess: ")

def validate_number(user_num, rand_num):
    cows, bulls = 0, 0
    for x in range(0, len(rand_num)):
        if user_num[x] == rand_num[x]:
            cows += 1
        elif user_num[x] in rand_num:
            bulls += 1

    print('{}: {} cows, {} bulls'.format(user_num,cows,bulls))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    while(True):
        count += 1
        user_num = ask_user()
        if user_num == 'exit':
            break
        elif int(user_num) == number:
            print('Congratulations! \nYou guessed the right number!\n{} 4 cows, 0 bulls\nGAME OVER'.format(number))
            print("it took you " +str(count) + ' tries')
            break
        else:
            validate_number(user_num,str(number))
```

Comment: Check following question, would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326099/how-can-i-limit-the-user-input-to-only-integers-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I made a recursion that checks the input value, hope it helps:

```
def check_num(user_num):
    try:
        user_num=int(user_num)
    except:

        if user_num == 'exit':
            return user_num

        else:
            print("please insert a 4 digit number")
            user_num = ask_user()
            user_num = check_num(user_num)

    return user_num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    while(True):
        count += 1

        user_num = ask_user()
        user_num = check_num(user_num)

        if user_num == 'exit':
            break
        else:

            if int(user_num) == number:
                print('Congratulations! \nYou guessed the right number!\n{} 4 cows, 0 bulls\nGAME OVER'.format(number))
                print("it took you " +str(count) + ' tries')
                break

            else:
                validate_number(str(user_num),str(number))
```