# Variable Input and Detection Method Issues in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm writing a code for a number guesser program. And I'm stuck on this what method in the code. The code is supposed to take in a user input of userMax and userMin. And if the user inputs something that isn't an integer the method will reprompt them to input a new userMax and userMin. Also the method is supposed to return the variables userMin and userMax. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code:

```
def range():
  print("What range do you want to guess?")
  userMin = input("Min:")
  userMax = input("Max: ")
  while isinstance(userMin, int) and isinstance(userMax, int) == False:
    print("Invalid Input. Try Again.")
    userMin = input("Min:")
    userMax = input("Max:")
  else:
    return userMin, userMax
range()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Try

```
def ranges():
  print("What range do you want to guess?")
  userMin = input("Min:")
  userMax = input("Max: ")
  try:
    return int(userMin), int(userMax)
  except:
    return ranges()
print(ranges())
```

Output

```
What range do you want to guess?                                                                               
Min:4                                                                                                          
Max: d                                                                                                         
What range do you want to guess?                                                                               
Min:                                                                                                           
Max: d                                                                                                         
What range do you want to guess?                                                                               
Min:df                                                                                                         
Max: fs                                                                                                        
What range do you want to guess?                                                                               
Min:3                                                                                                          
Max: 7                                                                                                         
(3, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**
The first problem with the program is that `input` method will always return a string. Thus, `isinstance(userMin, int)` will always be false.

Hint: Refer to the stackoverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326219/11640763

**Problem 2:** 
The program is successfully returning the variables but you are not printing those anywhere. So, your are unable to see the returned variables values while calling `range()` function.

Hint: Add a `print` statement.