# strictly no other user input rather than this 4 predefined options with Python

Tags: python

'''def addition(num1, num2):
return num1 + num2

def subtraction(num1, num2):
return num1 - num2

def multiplication(num1, num2):
return num1 * num2

def division(num1, num2):
return num1 / num2

selection = int(input("Select operations form 1, 2, 3, 4 :" '\n' "1.Addition, 2.Subtraction, 3.Multiplication, 4.Division \n "))
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if select == 1:
print(addition(num1, num2))

elif select == 2:
print(subtraction(num1, num2))

elif select == 3:
print(multiplication(num1, num2))

elif select == 4:
print(division(num1, num2))

else:

```
print("Invalid input")
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with while loop
read here
[How can I limit the user input to only integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326099/how-can-i-limit-the-user-input-to-only-integers-in-python)