# Defining a function that only accepts an integer as an input

Tags: python

My approach with this function is that it only accepts an integer as an input, otherwise if the person enters a letter or something else it goes back to the while loop and continues asking for the input until it receives the correct input which in this case it can only be 1-9.

```
import string
string.ascii_letters
def player_choice(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in list(range(1,10)) or space_check(board, position) or position in list[string.ascii_letters]:
        if position in list[string.ascii_letters]:
            pass
        position = int(input("Please enter a position(1-9): "))
    return position
```

I tried importing ascii_letters from the string library to tell python that if the input is inside of the  that list to go back to the while loop, but everytime I run the code i get a syntax error saying that the input only accepts an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit the user input to only integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326099/how-can-i-limit-the-user-input-to-only-integers-in-python)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

First solution using simple checkings

```py
def player_choice(board):
    while True:
        position = input("Please enter a position(1-9): ")
        if position.isdecimal() and len(position) == 1 and position != '0':
            position = int(position)
            break
    return position
```

Second solution using regex

```py
import re

def player_choice(board):
    while True:
        position = input("Please enter a position(1-9): ")
        if re.match('^[1-9]$', position):
            position = int(position)
            break
    return position
```

Comment: Are you aware that something like `'⑧'.isdigit()` yields `True`? The `⑧` is clearly not an integer value.

Comment: @Matthias I didn't know that. Funny behavior )

Comment: @Matthias I will change to a `isdecimal()`

Comment: Some months ago that was new for me too - after nearly 20 years of Python.

Comment: Both these solutions accept `0`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi my bad! Fixed them both

Answer (score -3):

Use typing.

def whatever(param: int):

Comment: Unless you use an interpreter that enforces them, type **hints** are just that -- _hints!_. Even if you were to use such an interpreter, typing it as an integer does nothing to ensure that the value returned by `input` is actually a numeric value.