# Is there a way do an input on python without writing any text to go with it?

Tags: python

Im trying to make a calculator but I want the user of the program to be able to just enter numbers.

Im kind of a noob and this is my first solo project

Comment: are you looking to do `num = float(input())`?

Comment: what do you mean by "just enter numbers" what would a sample input look like?

Comment: I guess he wants to exclude all input other than int / float values.
You need to read your input and check if the input is of type integer/float. If not, just repeat. To achieve this use a try / catch block which fires a ValueError exception

Comment: So, for this very reason, I think "writing a calculator" is a bad beginner project because it is either trivial, otherwise, it's a little advanced. Basically, it boils down to *parsing the string input*. You could use something like `eval`, which just evaluates the string as if it were Python code (using the Python parser!), but that is generally bad practice. Otherwise, you want to write your own parser. There are good tools for doing that. You can also do it from scratch (which is an interesting exercise in itself)! Tons of beginners end up asking the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit the user input to only integers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326099/how-can-i-limit-the-user-input-to-only-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

So to do something like that, you would only use the input() function. (e.g. (variable) = input("")). And then to make it an int (AKA, a number), you would type int((variable name)). Hope that helps.

Comment: also, if you want it to be a decimal number, then you would have to do: (variable name) = float((variable name))

Comment: @AthenaDapolias27 Also,, if that works, It'd if you could mark it was an answer. You don't have to, I'm just trying to unlock upvoting